# 2 versions of PHP installed Mac OS X causing xdebug fail

Tags: php, macos, netbeans, xdebug

Mac OS X 10.8.5.  I am trying to get Netbeans running using xdebug.  To date I have tried XAMPP and MAMP without success.  Apparently there is a native PHP on the Mac that I can't figure out how to remove:

```
sh-3.2# which php
/usr/bin/php
sh-3.2# php -v
PHP 5.3.26 (cli) (built: Jul  7 2013 19:05:08) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

However, the PHP in my MAMP installation shows:

```
sh-3.2# pwd
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin
sh-3.2# ./php -v
PHP 5.5.3 (cli) (built: Sep 18 2013 14:31:13)
```

I followed the instructions on this page:
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-mac-os.html
but xdebug does not show up in the list of extensions on the phpinfo page.    I downloaded the latest xdebug by the way (2.2.3).  I've also tried the tailored instructions here: http://xdebug.org/wizard.php with no luck.

I'm certain it's because if the mismatched php's.  How do I remove the native PHP to get this working?
Thanks!
Roberto

Comment: Can you output the following two commands? `/usr/bin/php -i | grep -i xdebug` and `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/php -i | grep -i xdebug`

Comment: @Daniel: `sh-3.2# /usr/bin/php -i | grep -i xdebug`
`sh-3.2# /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/php -i | grep -i xdebug`
`sh-3.2#`

Comment: i.e. no output from either command

Comment: That means that the issue isn't with the default php installation since it shows xdebug isn't installed/configured with mamp. Did you add the xdebug section to your /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5/php.ini file?